# unable to crop the valid psd file in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, crop

[image]I have a PSD file which contains many Layers and each layer contains either some image or text. i want to crop the selection Area from that psd file..while doing that, it throwing an error please explain how to resolve this issue

Comment: Standard troubleshooting. Relaunch app, trash prefs, reboot system... etc.

Comment: you are trying to crop a folder

Comment: try and use the crop tool (fifth tool in your box) instead of cropping to a selection.

Comment: @johnSmith having a Layer Group highlighted in the Layer Panel makes no difference. The crop **always** refers to the document dimensions.. the Layer Panel has nothing to do with cropping.

Comment: @Scott i tried relaunching App, rebootsystem...but also getting same error...for another psd file i am not getting these error...one thing i want to tell that this psd with 450Mb size..

Comment: You should try asking this on the Adobe forum as its a technical problem. The only thing I could dig up is this http://forums.adobe.com/message/5192546

Comment: Actually, I seem to remember having had something like this - I saved a copy with another file name, opened it, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Merge all layers and crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to crop image or psd:

1. Select crop tool from tool box and apply.
2. First select area with rectangle marquee tool then `Image > Crop`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop an Image or anything with selection and facing
the problem > The problem to all solution is to just 
    1. select an area to be crop
    2. press CTR+SHIFT+C for copy merged
    3. CTR + N new file
    4. CTR + V Paste you will be getting only selected area.